# Wordpress - when a link to a page is shared on facebook, how can I choose the preview image/video

Tags: php, html, wordpress, web, sharing

https://www.wildcardtheatre.co.uk/signal-fires/ < I have this page here but when I share it on Facebook the website logo shows instead of the video of the page in the preview.

How can I tell WordPress this page should show a preview video instead?

Thank you!

[image]